# create custom masterpages - is it better to copy v4.master and then modify

Tags: master-page

I would like to have 2 materpages one for the publishing site and one for none publishing site.
Any ideas the best way to get started?
Thanks in Advance

Comment: It completely depends on the customization wanted on the masterpage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's always recommended to start from an already existing master. Depending on your needs that may be the v4 or any other master.

[This codeplex project](http://startermasterpages.codeplex.com/) may also be very valuable when it comes to your problem.